# Getting 400 'bad request' for deployed django app with apache2 + mod_wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, bad-request

I am running 2 django apps on same server (both are almost the same). First app is running without any issue in virtual env and prod mode. But for the 2nd deployed app I am getting the bad request error even its running in virtual env without any issue.

I set 775 for the whole project and www-data as owner.

My apache .conf file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName prod-domain.de
<Directory /opt/myproject/mysite/mysite> 
 <Files wsgi.py>
     Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /opt/myproject/mysite/media/
Alias /static/ /opt/myproject/mysite/base/static/
<Directory /static/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /media/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-myproject.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-myproject.log combined
</VirtualHost>
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/myproject/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /opt/myproject/mysite/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

My settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["prod-domain.de"]
```

[...]

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'base/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'myproject/static/', ]

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

I played around a lot with apache conf and the settings.py but apache doesn't show any error in the logs and now I stucked hardly.

Also tried

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

with no effect.

Comment: what do you mean with "...even its running in virtual env without any issue".  In which circumstances the app is running without error message?

Comment: Since I have only basic knowledge in python I hope I am getting your question: I created a virtual environment, opened port 8000 and running there with DEBUG = False. In this case the app is running as it should do. And I need to run it on port 80 / 443 ...

Comment: so I understand you have two apps running ok with runserver and now you try to serve them as virtual hosts in a Apache Server. App1 is running, App2 returns a 400. I would first recommend to exchange the "ServerName prod-domain.de" between the two virtual hosts and see if in this case app2 is running and App1 delivers the 400. Is there anything in access.log?

Comment: the WSGIScriptAlias needs to be inside the virtual host declaration

Comment: access log: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 322 "http://prod-domain.de/" ...

I did a misconfiguration on wsgi.load and got in error.log for app2:
"Embedded mode of mod_wsgi disabled by runtime configuration: /opt/app1/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py"  --> Its pointing to app1 -- 

app1 is running successfully with runserver + apache virtual host. app2 is running successfully with runserver, but not apache virtual host (each app has its own .conf. Now I'm beginning to believe that two wsgi instances cannot run on same apache web server...

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias inside virtual host is causing many errors: page shows 500 internal server error and the logs: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'" and lot more like:


[wsgi:error] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[wsgi:error] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
[wsgi:error] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
[wsgi:error] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked

Comment: yes, but exactly that means that your wsgi.py is being called ... at least tried to. please put the whole error trace in the post

Comment: 2 apps as virtual host is possibel ... see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141768/how-to-deploy-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-in-windows/75145306?noredirect=1#comment132662406_75145306

Comment: man thanks for you help, its fixed now. Moved WSGIScriptAlias inside virtual host (strange its working with that outside for app1...) and did some changes on wsgi.py.

Comment: it works outside but then it is global and you need a individual one for each virt.host

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after moved WSGIScriptAlias inside the VirtualHost tag in my apache `.conf` file and following on `wsgi.py`:

```
import os, sys

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

sys.path.append('opt/myproject/mysite')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```