# How to configure multiple sites with django and apache server with wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I configure two sites in my server, but when trying access to my second site apache2 redirect me to first site, I want to serve tow sites in the same server but not working

This is my configuration of my first site:

```
  GNU nano 5.4                                                  first_site.com.conf                                                           
<VirtualHost first_site.com:80>
    #ServerAdmin admin@soporte.localhost
    ServerName inscripcion.uepbi.com
    #ServerAlias www.first_site.com
    #DocumentRoot /home/sites/first_site
    #DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/sites/first_site/staticfiles/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /home/sites/first_site/staticfiles/
    <Directory /home/sites/first_site/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /uploads/ /home/sites/first_site/uploads/
    <Directory /home/sites/first_site/uploads>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sites/college_system/college_system>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} == "first_site.com"
                Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} == "www.first_site.com"
                Options
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess first_site python-path=/home/sites/first_site python-home=/home/sites/first_site_env
    #WSGIPythonHome /home/sites/first_site
    #WSGIPythonPath /home/sites/first_site
    WSGIProcessGroup first_site
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sites/first_site/first_site/wsgi.py process-group=first_site application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    Redirect "/" "https://first_site.com/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.first_site.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =first_site.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !on [OR]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://first_site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

This my configuration for my second site:

```
<VirtualHost second_site.com:8080>
    #ServerAdmin admin@soporte.localhost
    ServerName second_site.com
    #ServerAlias www.second_site.com
    #DocumentRoot /home/sites/second_site
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_demo_college.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_demo_college.log combined
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/sites/second_site/staticfiles/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /home/sites/second_site/staticfiles/
    <Directory /home/sites/second_site/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/sites/second_site/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /uploads/ /home/sites/second_site/uploads/
    <Directory /home/sites/second_site/uploads>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sites/second_site/second_site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} == "second_site.com"
                Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} == "www.second_site.com"
                Options
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess second_site python-path=/home/sites/second_site python-home=/home/sites/second_site_env
    WSGIProcessGroup second_site
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sites/second_site/second_site/wsgi.py process-group=second_site application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    #Redirect permanent "/" "http://second_site.com/
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.second_site.com [OR]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =second_site.com
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !on [OR]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://second_site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The first site is configure with ssl this is the config file:

```
  GNU nano 5.4                                               first_site.com-ssl.conf                                                         
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost first_site.com:443>
    #ServerAdmin admin@soporte.localhost
    ServerName first_site.com
    #ServerAlias www.first_site.com
    #DocumentRoot /home/sites/first_site
    #DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/sites/first_site/staticfiles/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /home/sites/first_site/staticfiles/
    <Directory /home/sites/first_site/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /uploads/ /home/sites/first_site/uploads/
    <Directory /home/sites/first_site/uploads>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sites/first_site/first_site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} == "first_site.com"
            Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} == "www.first_site.com"
            Options
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess first_site2 python-path=/home/sites/first_site python-home=/home/sites/first_site_env
    #WSGIPythonHome /home/sites/first_site_env
    #WSGIPythonPath /home/sites/first_site
    WSGIProcessGroup first_site2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sites/first_site/first_site/wsgi.py process-group=first_site
    #Redirect "/" "https://first_site.com/

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/first_site.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/first_site.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

All ports is configured the first_site listen on port 80 and  443 for ssl
And the second_site is liston on port 8080

This is my configuration of ports.conf file:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8080
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

1. vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Thanks for help me
If you needs more information you can ask me
I hope you a good day

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141768/how-to-deploy-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-in-windows/75145306?noredirect=1#comment132662406_75145306

Comment: Hello @Razenstein thanks for answer, I have configured on my linux debian the file /etc/hosts

Comment: @Razenstein this is my configuration
10.89.51.32 first_site.com www.first_site.com
10.89.51.32 second_site.com www.second_site.com

Comment: I would recommend you to first install the two sites without ssl and when they run, add the ssl stuff

Comment: I configured my wsgi.py file based on answer shared but not working, Apache continue redirect me to my first_site, I can't access on my second_site

Comment: @Razenstein I tried it but not working, Apache redirect me to my first_site on port 80 and first_site not working without SSL config and modified the ports.conf for Apache not listen on port 443