# Can you have multiple python versions with Conda and Apache2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache2, conda, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to wrap my head around configuring Apache2 to run my Django project which runs by using conda. After switching recently from venv the goal is to run multiple projects with their own environments.

So far so good and there are multiple tutorials how to set this up.

What I do not understand is the relationship between the different python versions and mod_wsgi. I can compile mod_wsgi either on the system or in a conda env, but then it will always be tied to a specific version.

Does that mean I have to have all my conda envs run the same python version?
Or is it possible to create multiple mod_wsgi modules for every desired python version?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache loads 1 mod_wsgi at startup which is built for/with one specific python version. There is various blocking effects/errors if you mix mod_wsgi with wrong python version. But it is no problem to configure virtual host with different envs ... but with same python version!!

[How to deploy multiple django apps on apache in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141768/how-to-deploy-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-in-windows/75145306#75145306)

Comment: Thank you. One follow-up question: Is there any Apache2 alternative that can host different python versions in multiple Conda environments?

Comment: You would need to run parallel several independent instances (possible also with Apache) but on ports like 8080, 8081, 8082 with in front a server as so called "reverse proxy" listening at port 80/443 and forwarding the traffic to your hosts.

Comment: Thank you so much. It leads me to one last question: Does Apache and the mod_wsgi module itself need a version of python? I'm running Debian which only goes to 3.9 and I don't wanna mess with it. What if all my Condas are at 3.11 and I compile a modwsgi using those. Would that work? Or does the System's python version still play into it?

Comment: just go into the virtenv / pip install mod_wsgi / mod_wsgi-express .... like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141768/how-to-deploy-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-in-windows/75145306#75145306  ....should work